# How to schedule a firebase notification to be sent after an hour

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, cron, firebase-cloud-messaging

I wanted to schedule a Firebase notification to be sent after an hour of placing an order. I'm using Nodejs and an HTTP request to send the notification. The notification is not recurring, I just need it to be sent after an hour of order placement and then stop. I already know how to send a notification, I just wanted to know how to schedule it to run after an hour.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to send the notification via a Cloud Function. You'll find in the following [article](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-schedule-a-cloud-function-to-run-in-the-future-in-order-to-build-a-firestore-document-ttl-754f9bf3214a) all the details on "How to schedule a Cloud Function to run in the future with Cloud Tasks".

The code in the Cloud Function will be very similar to the code you are using with your Node.js server, since [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) are based on the Admin SDK.

Comment: I don't want to add additional dependency to the project (cloud functions) in this case, which requires blaze plan. Is there no way to do it in nodejs server?